# Find the link at position 18 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 7 times

Tags: python

Actual problem: Start at: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Kristie.html
Find the link at position 18 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 7 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve.
Hint: The first character of the name of the last page that you will load is:

i have solution and i need shere it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it consists mostly of a link, and there is not even a question stated.

Answer (score 1):

thisis solution:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_more = ssl.CERT_NONE
repeat = 7
count_repeat = 1
position = 18
current_position = 1

html = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Kristie.html'
print(html)
while count_repeat <= repeat:    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(html, context=ctx).read(), 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags: 
        if current_position == position:
            html = tag.get('href',None)
            print(html)
            current_position = 1
            break
        current_position += 1
    count_repeat += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).